# ${n\choose m}={n\choose n-m}$ Proof

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I need to prove the following: ${n\choose m}={n\choose n-m}$

With the definition: ${n\choose m}= \left\{ 
                \begin{array}{ll}
                    \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} & \textrm{für \(m\leq n\)} \\
                    0 & \textrm{für \(m>n\)} 
                \end{array}
               \right.$

and $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$.

I'm stuck at how to even start this. Using induction? Any help would be appreciated, I tried to search SA, but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Substitute $m = n-m'$ in your definition then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Just use [factorial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Factorial_formula).

$${n\choose m}= \frac{n!}{m! \cdot (n-m)!}$$

---

**Solution**:

$${n\choose n-m} = \frac{n!}{(n-m)! \cdot (n -(n-m))!} = \frac{n!}{(n-m)! \cdot m!}
= \frac{n!}{m! \cdot (n-m)!} = {n\choose m}$$

I believe, rest is obvious.

Answer (score 3):

**An other way:**

to choose $m$ balls in a box that contain $n$ balls is equivalent that to not choose the $n-m$ other balls.

Answer (score 0):

$$ {n\choose n-m} = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!(n-(n-m))!} = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!m!} = {n \choose m}  $$